# Set OnClickListener for items in ListView with 2 Views

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I have a ListView, with items with this layout:

```
<LinearLayout ...>            
    <LinearLayout ...>
       <!--Elements -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout ...>
       <!--Elements -->
    </LinearLayout>            
</LinearLayout>
```

So my items have two different sections. I want to be able to setup different onclickListener inside each item(one for each LinearLayout). I have tried so far to override the onListItemClick, but it doesnt seem to work properly:

```
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) { 
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)v;
    vg.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mCtx, "element1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
        }
    });
    vg.getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mCtx, "element2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
        }
    });

}
```

Any ideas how to tackle the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that `vg.getChildAt(0)` and `vg.getChildAt(1)` returning `Linearlayout`

Comment: It doesnt matters, what I want now is to set differents events for to the listview Item.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use set `onclicklistener` to all elements inside ListView.
I have created a listview. set an adapter to the listview. My adapter is reponsible to show each element of the listview. so inside `getView()` I will assign onclicklistener to all the elemnts to whom i want to get the click event.

### Example

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        holder.text.setText("item "+position);
        holder.image.setTag(data.get(position));
        holder.image.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.text.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(position), activity, holder.image);
        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("...clicked view is...."+arg0);
    }
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a OnClickListener for each list item, but you do need to find each listview, e.g. in your activity OnCreate

```
listView1 = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
listView2 = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.ListView2);
```

then your onListItemClick becomes -

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) { 
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

if (l.equals(listView1))
{
    switch (position)
    {
       case 0:
         Toast.makeText(mCtx, "list1-element1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
       case 1:
         Toast.makeText(mCtx, "list1-element2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
    }
}
else
{
    switch (position)
    {
       case 0:
         Toast.makeText(mCtx, "list2-element1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
       case 1:
         Toast.makeText(mCtx, "list2-element2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
    }
}


}
```

Unless I've misunderstood what your trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something here, but isn't the neat version to go with setting:

```
aListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

And then implement:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "List view click: " + getListView().getCheckedItemCount());
    Toast.makeText(this,
            String.valueOf(getListView().getCheckedItemCount()),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}
```

The above solutions has been available since API level 1