# Using OnItemLongClick Listeners with a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have a `ListView` which contains entries given by layout file **entry.xml** I want to start with the `ImageView` visibility set to `View.GONE` and `onItemLongClick` change that to `View.VISIBLE`. The `ListView` entry that is long clicked would remain highlighted.

I then want to add an `onClickListener` to the `ImageView` (whilst its visible) so that the clicked `ListView` entry can be deleted by tapping the image.

There also needs to be a second `OnClickListener` on the `ListView` entry so that if it has been long clicked and highlighted this can be undone by (short)clicking on the entry. This would restore the `ImageView` back to `View.GONE`.

**How can I achieve this?**

---

**listview.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**entry.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/entry_deleteicon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:maxHeight="40dp"
        android:maxWidth="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/delete"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/entry_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**My Custom Adapter**

```
private class SaveAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private int resourceId;
        private SaveHolder[] holder;

        public SaveAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
            super(context, resource);
            this.resourceId=resource;
            this.holder = new SaveHolder[5];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
            holder[position] = null;
            if(row==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

                holder[position] = new SaveHolder();
                holder[position].textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.entry_name);
                holder[position].iconDelete = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.entry_deleteicon);              
                row.setTag(holder[position]);
            }else{
                holder[position] = (SaveHolder) row.getTag();
            }
            holder[position].textName.setText("name");
            return row;
        }
    }

    static class SaveHolder{
        TextView textName;
        ImageView iconDelete;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
private ImageView tmpImageView;

...

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long arg3){
    tmpImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_IMAGEVIEW_ID);
    tmpImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int arg2, long arg3){
    tmpImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

...
```

hope this work for you...

Comment: For anyone who comes across this post, note that the `onItemLongClick` and `onItemClick` are supposed to be inside of `new AdapterView.onItemLongClickListener()` and `new AdapterView.onItemClickListener()` objects respectively.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add an [OnItemLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html) too your `ListView` for handling the visibility of your `ImageView`
2. Add an [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) too your `ListView` for handling the your wanted functionality there.
3. Add an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) too your `ImageView` and handle the the deletion of an item there. You can make use of a custom `Adapter` and override the getView-method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6200974/1479570)

Comment: if i'm just using listview.SetOnItemLongClickListener(...) how do i access the ImageView for each entry?

Comment: Can you add some code to demonstrate how you would do step 1 please?

Comment: [This tutorial](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/) shows you how to use a custom Adapter. Set the onClickListener on the ImageView in the getView(..) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
Update your SaveAdapter like this.
->Implement listener for imageview.
->Add visible and hide function for imageview.





    private class SaveAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
                private int resourceId;
                private SaveHolder[] holder;
        int highLightedItemNumber = -1;

                public SaveAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
                    super(context, resource);
                    this.resourceId=resource;
                    this.holder = new SaveHolder[5];
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return 5;
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
                    holder[position] = null;
                    if(row==null){
                        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                        row = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

                        holder[position] = new SaveHolder();
                        holder[position].textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.entry_name);
                        holder[position].iconDelete = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.entry_deleteicon);              
                        row.setTag(holder[position]);
                    }else{
                        holder[position] = (SaveHolder) row.getTag();
                    }
        if(highlightedItemNumber == position)
        {
        holder[position].iconDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
        holder[position].iconDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
                    holder[position].textName.setText("name");
        holder[position].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
        //Perform your delete operation here;

        }
        });
                    return row;
                }
            }

        public void highlightImageView(int itemNumber)
        {
        highlightedItemPosition = itemNumber;
         notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void disableHighlightedItem()
        {
        highlightedItemPosition = -1;
         notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
            static class SaveHolder{
                TextView textName;
                ImageView iconDelete;
            }

}
```

Now in your mainActivity, Here you are creating listView instances.

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourlistviewId);
final SaveAdapter adapter = new SaveAdapter(this, resource); //your resource id.


listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                adapter.disableHighlightedItem();
            }

        });


listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
        adapter.highlightImageView(position);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Long click on listitem will make image visible and need to highlight that Listitem(change the background of the item)
   i think you are not suppose to have problem in this section
2. onckick on image will make that list  item delete.(this is manageable in adapter class)

For this you need to delete the item from the arraylist you are sending adapter class like this

```
arrayList.remove(position);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

1. on click on listitem will change that item in old state.To maintain all this highlight and nonHighlight scenario you need to maintain an ArrayList.in starting fill the arraylist with 0's equal to size of list.On long click change the arraylist postion value with 1 and on click change that 1 to 0.