# Android ListView onItemClick update TextView

Tags: android, listviewitem

Back to Android programming after a 4 year hiatus from a few short projects. Just the sheer volume of information to digest is overwhelming. So, I am stuck when creating functionality that I have working in an old project that uses a ListView and customer Adapter, but fails to work now.

Android Studio 3.4.2, Java

I have a ListView with two TextViews per row. I populate the view with a custom ArrayList Adapater. In the getView() method, I successfully fill 286 rows of data in the ListView. This works well and I can scroll and see all data.

I registered an onItemClick event and when the user clicks on a row, I want to update the first TextView in that row with the number of times that row has been clicked.

```
checkListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int listIndex, long l) {
        // Increment count
        String numObserved = checklistItems.get(listIndex).incrementNumObserved();

        // Update count view
        TextView seenTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.SeenCount);
        seenTextView.setText(numObserved);
    }
});
```

It correctly updates the TextView with the incremented count, however, if I scroll down one page, it has also set the count on another row; etc. all the way down the List.

What am I doing wrong here?

Don't know what else I need to provide, so please let me know and I will provide it, but it seems that this is the crux of the issue.

Also, two follow-up questions.

1) When is the 3rd parameter (int) ever different from the 4th parameter (long) and why? I have read the DOC on this and I can't figure out the distinction between the two parameters in the onItemClick() method.

2) I want to be able to tell if the user clicked on the first TextView or the second TextView. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: 0) The issue is most likely caused by your implementation of getView() - it looks like you do not set the count value explicitly there, so all the list items for which a View is recycled inherit the count value which you set in the OnItemClickListener 1) I suppose you will get different values for adapter position and row id if your adapter implements  getItemId() and returns something other than the position 2) Yes, if you use two OnClickListeners for each row (set them in getView() ) instead  of

Comment: Thx. You are correct. I was not explicitly setting the value for the first TextView in GetView(). GACK! It makes sense now that you have pointed it out. 
1) gotcha. 2) Not sure I understand. I currently implement setOnItemClickListener() in my activity and declare the onItemClick() event as you can see above. Are you saying that I would need to declare two OnClickListeners in my getView() for each time getView is called? For each row?
Thanks so much.

Comment: Take a look at [Set OnClickListener for items in ListView with 2 Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200604/set-onclicklistener-for-items-in-listview-with-2-views), especially the answer by Sunil Kumar Sahoo